# Clicking "print" in Chrome causes Flash object/SWF to crash

Tags: google-chrome, flash, printing, reload

I don't know if it's an issue with a JS conflict, possibly a hidden jQuery/CSS thing, an invisible WebKit href inclusion, or just a bug in Chrome Version 43.0.2357.130 (64-bit).

The intent is to print the contents of a Flash drawing game--which was previously working on all browsers as well as Chrome--but this combination of Chrome and newer website code, clicking on print forces the Flash object to reload...which of course empties it so nothing will print.

Has anyone encountered this kind of behavior before? FWIW this site is using the Zurb Foundation system, along with jQuery and the http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js plugin.

(Because it's using Foundation, we have three instances of the SWF specified by size, though all other views are empty except the active one. I tested to see if this was a possible problem by removing all but 1 object on the page, but it made no difference to this behavior.)

Comment: Update: I've so far narrowed it down to foundation.css. When this is omitted, the page is unstyled, but the Flash object doesn't reload on print.

Comment: Update 2: On Chrome, this line in foundation.css causes the flash object to reload, when invoking the print command, in anything other than small view:

`.hide-for-small-only, .hide-for-small-up, .hide-for-small, .hide-for-small-down, .show-for-medium-only, .show-for-medium-up, .show-for-medium, .hide-for-medium-down, .show-for-large-only, .show-for-large-up, .show-for-large, .hide-for-large-down, .show-for-xlarge-only, .show-for-xlarge-up, .show-for-xxlarge-only, .show-for-xxlarge-up { display: none !important; }`

Comment: Update 3: It appears that Chrome's print preview function--which overrides the system print dialog in OS X--is at least partly to blame: it is crashing the Flash object and thus causing it to reload (and empty). However, this behavior does not happen at <400px screen sizes. Curious.

Comment: Update 4!: the show-for-large (and variants) and show-for-medium (and variants) Foundation.css tags are causing Flash to crash on print. Removing these prevents the behavior.

But these are obviously core foundation tags, so there is as yet no solution.

And one qualifier: even when these tags are disabled, the print preview is blank.

Answer (score 0):

To anyone who might by now be beating their head against a wall trying to understand this: I've discovered the specific issue that causes Chrome to crash Flash objects when it launches its print preview dialog:

Because enabling/disabling the `.show-for-large-up` and `.show-for-medium-only` tags (among others?) in Foundation.css were modifying the behavior, I created our own Modernizr-enabled screen size detection function to hide/show our divs without Foundation's tags. When I did that, printing on Chrome worked as it should.

Then, thinking I didn't need to invoke Modernizr/JS functionality when Foundation's own CSS file already accomplished this using @media queries, I deleted that function and simply added in `display: block` for our new custom hide/show tags. This caused Chrome to once again crash Flash objects.

So the issue is that Chrome's print preview dialog crashes Flash objects when CSS is using @media queries to determine the visibility of [at least] large- and medium-view content divs.

This points to a Chromium issue as printing Flash objects works fine on Safari, Firefox and Explorer. Specifically, the Chrome print preview dialog is not playing nice with Foundation's @media queries--and possibly the CSS of other third party providers.